# What conditions are needed for a uniform bound on the deviation of a random variable from its expectation?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

The title is quite clear, but a few specifics may help guide where I'm coming from.

I have a probability space defined by a Poisson distribution over the non-negative integers with some mean $\mu$. I have a random variable $X$ over this space, and I wish to prove a tight bound on the deviation of $X$ from its expectation.

I'm familiar with the Chernoff/Hoeffding bounds which bound deviation with high probability, but I was wondering what is needed to give bounds that aren't probabilistic? For example, is $Var(X) = o(E(X)^2)$ enough to do this? [Edit: I can also phrase my problem as having a sequence of random variables depending on some parameter $n \to \infty$] Does this depend on the meaning of "almost everywhere" in my particular probability space? (does "almost nowhere" mean "everywhere except on a finite set" for my particular space?)

What sort of conditions might I impose on the probability space so that I could prove a statement like:

> There is a constant $c$ such that $|X - E(X)| < c$ except on a finite set.

I imagine my brain is host to a menagerie of misconceptions about probability spaces, so please excuse me if I'm saying nonsensical things.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by a probability space defined by a Poison distribution? Is the variable $X$ supposed to be a random variable on the non-negative integers?

Comment: Yes, so for example $n$ might be Poisson distributed on non-negative integers with mean 1, and $X$ might be defined by $X = \binom{n}{2}$. Of course this doesn't work for my exact question above, but gives an idea of the kind of random variables I'm thinking about.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mathbb{N}_0 = \mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$. Based on your comment above, let me give my impression of the scenario you're considering. Let $N$ be a Poisson random variable and remember that $N$ is a (measurable) function from some probability space $\Omega$ taking values in $\mathbb{N}_0$. Let $g : D \subset \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be some (measurable) function such that $\mathbb{N}_0 \subset D$ (so that $g(N)$ makes sense). We want to ask when there exists a $c > 0$ such that 
$$ \big|g(N) - E[g(N)]\big|<c $$

I assume we will be working with a "nice enough" $g$ so that there is some $\nu \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $E[g(N)] = \nu$. This all translates to the question: When is it possible that there is some $c > 0$ such that 
$$
\sup\left\{ \left|\, g\big(N(\omega)\big) - \nu \,\right|\,:\,\omega \in \Omega \right\}<c
$$
since you are trying to uniformly bound this for all $\omega \in \Omega$. But, this is a critique on $g$, not on $\Omega$ nor $N$. Once you know that $N$ is a Poisson random variable, there is nothing you can do to "adjust" it or the probability space to make it "nicer" because that "adjustment" will no longer leave you with a Poisson random variable. Now I claim that 
$$
\sup\left\{ \left|\, g\big(N(\omega)\big) - \nu \,\right|\,:\,\omega \in \Omega \right\}<c
$$
is equivalent to the existence of some other $C$ (depending on $\nu$) such that
$$
\sup\left\{ \left|\, g\big(N(\omega)\big) \right|\,:\,\omega \in \Omega \right\}<C
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
\sup\left\{ \left|\, g(n) \right|\,:\,n \in \mathbb{N}_0 \right\}<C
$$
So, what results is that $g(N) - \nu$ is uniformly bounded if and only if the restriction of $g$ to $\mathbb{N}_0$ is uniformly bounded. Moreover, if $g$ is bounded (and measurable), then $E[g(N)] = \nu$ exists. So, the answer to your question is that $g(N) - E[g(N)]$ is uniformly bounded (over $\omega \in \Omega$) if and only if $g$ is uniformly bounded on $\mathbb{N}_0$.

Comment: Okay. So what, if any, techniques are generally used to show this? Can this be done by arguments on variance or something else if $g$ is not known to be uniformly bounded a priori?

Comment: If $N$ is a Poisson random variable with parameter $\lambda >0$, then the mean and variance of $N$ are $\lambda$. It's set as soon as you specify $\lambda$. If you wanted to have a Poisson random variable with mean $\mu$ and then try to adjust the variance $\sigma^2$ by making $\sigma^2 \neq \mu$, then $N$ would no longer be a Poisson random variable. If $g$ is unbounded on $\mathbb{N}_0$ then there is no argument you can make so that $g(N)$ is uniformly bounded in the way you describe.

Comment: I mean I don't know if $g$ is unbounded, and I'm wondering if there are any sufficient conditions that can prove it's bounded except on a finite set (which I hope means the same thing as measure zero on a discrete probability space). And since $g$ is a random variable which is a function of $N$, its variance can be something else entirely.